# Plotting distribution of bootstrapped values in R

Tags: r, distribution, density-plot

I need to fit a S-shaped distribution (`y = 0~1`) with 95% confidence interval, and get the `x` values where `y=5%` (termed as `hc5`). The original input data file named `ZnOLC50.txt`:

```
LC50    Proportion
0.089    0.071428571
0.16    0.214285714
1.155    0.357142857
1.51    0.5
3.97    0.642857143
573.8    0.785714286
789    0.928571429


# Load data

>require(MASS)

>require(ggplot2)

>SSDZnOLC50<-read.delim("ZnOLC50.txt", header = TRUE)

>fitSSDZnOLC50<-fitdistr(SSDZnOLC50$LC50, 'lognormal')


# Extract hc5
>(hc5 <- qlnorm(0.05, meanlog = fitSSDZnOLC50$estimate[1], sdlog = fitSSDZnOLC50$estimate[2]))
[1] 0.01789181


>myboot <- function(fitSSDZnOLC50, p){

# resample from fitted distribution

>xr <- rlnorm(fitSSDZnOLC50$n, meanlog = fitSSDZnOLC50$estimate[1], sdlog = fitSSDZnOLC50$estimate[2])

# fit distribition to new data

>fitr <- fitdistr(xr, 'lognormal')
# return HCp

>hc5r <- qlnorm(p, meanlog = fitr$estimate[1], sdlog = fitr$estimate[2])
return(hc5r)
}


# Get 95% confidence interval
>set.seed(1234)
>hc5_boot <- replicate(1000, myboot(fitSSDZnOLC50, p = 0.05))

>quantile(hc5_boot, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))

    2.5%          50%        97.5% 
0.0007278486 0.0370062459 1.4272168899
```

Then I want to draw the `hc5` distribution based on the generated matrix `hc5_boot`. First I tried this:

```
curve(dnorm(x,mean(hc5_boot),sd(hc5_boot)),xlim=c(-1,10),col="Red",lwd=1)
```

and get the curve as shown in

[image]

Then I also tried

```
> df <- as.data.frame(hc5_boot)

> ggplot(df, aes(x=hc5_boot)) + geom_density() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,4))
```

and get the curve as shown in

[image]

However, based on the observation, none of those curves seem like to fit the `2.5%` quantile of `0.0007278486`, as the density values are not even close to 0 when `x = 0`.

So I was wondering what is wrong and how should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to graph the cumulative distribution rather than the density function. To do this, use the `pnorm` function rather than `dnorm` which produces the pdf. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1234)
mySample <- rnorm(100, 1, 5)
curve(pnorm(x,mean(mySample),sd(mySample)),xlim=c(-10,10),col="Red",lwd=1)
```

[image]